# Rolling log files issue with Spark

Tags: java, log4j

I have a rolling log file setup in my `log4j.xml` file. The logs are getting updated properly in the log file location i setup for. But, the logs are not getting archived properly and so I am missing the old log data.

Given below is my `log4j.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Properties>
        <!--<Property name="log-path">/adshome/rcast31/logs</Property>-->
        <Property name="log-path">/gmdl/grd/rawData/logs</Property>
        <Property name="grd-log-name">grd-spark-info</Property>
        <Property name="archive">${log-path}/archive</Property>
        <Property name="retentionAge">45d</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="info-image" fileName="${log-path}/${grd-log-name}.log"
                     filePattern="${archive}/${grd-log-name}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L (%t) - %m%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
                <Delete basePath="${archive}" maxDepth="1">
                    <IfFileName glob="${grd-log-name}*.log*" />
                    <IfLastModified age="${retentionAge}" />
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.aexp.grd" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="info-image"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="info-image" level="INFO"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I see separate log files with older dates are created but it doesn't have that day's logging information in it. Either is is empty or only getting rolled up partially. Please let me know what I am missing!

Comment: It's not a Spark specific problem, is it?